# How to check token expiration at interceptors android retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

I would like to handle token expiration by myself and send request for new tokens. I have such condition:

```
sp.getLong("expires_in", 0) - sp.getLong("time_delta", 0) - System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000 <= 60
```

This condition checks when my token will become expired and I have to send a new request from interceptor. I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52837981/retrofit-handling-token-expiration) question also. I have created such interceptor:

```
class RefreshTokens(cont: Context) : Interceptor{
    val context = cont
    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        var tokenIsUpToDate = false
        val sp = context.getSharedPreferences("app_data", 0)
        if (sp.getLong("expires_in", 0) - sp.getLong("time_delta", 0) - System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000 <= 60) {
            Singleton.apiService(context).getNewToken(ReqAccessToken(context.getSharedPreferences("app_data", 0).getString("refresh_token", ""))).enqueue(object : Callback<ResNewTokens>, retrofit2.Callback<ResNewTokens> {
                override fun onResponse(call: Call<ResNewTokens>, response: retrofit2.Response<ResNewTokens>) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful) {
                        tokenIsUpToDate = true
                    }
                }

                override fun onFailure(call: Call<ResNewTokens>, t: Throwable) {

                }

            })

            return if (tokenIsUpToDate) {
                chain.proceed(chain.request())
            } else {
                chain.proceed(chain.request())
            }

        } else {
            val response = chain.proceed(chain.request())
            when (response.code) {
                401->{
                    chain.request().url
                    response.request.newBuilder()
                            .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + context.getSharedPreferences("app_data", 0).getString("access_token", "")!!)
                            .build()
                }
                500 -> {
                    Toast.makeText(context, context.getString(R.string.server_error_500), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
            return response
        }
    }
}
```

I can't imagine how to add return condition to my code. I know about `Authentificator` but when I use it I send one more request which response gives me 401 error for token updating. When I use `Authentificator` I send such requests:

1. Request with old access_token -> 401 error
2. Request for the new tokens -> 200 OK
3. Request with new access_token -> 200 OK

So I would like to remove 1 request which will give error and send request for a new tokens. But I have to problems:

1. I don't know how to fix my interceptor for solving this task
2. I don't know how to repeat request which I was going to make like in Authentificator

Maybe someone knows how to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to share my own solution which works good as I see:

```
class AuthToken(context: Context) : Interceptor {
    var cont = context
    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        val sp = cont.getSharedPreferences("app_data", 0)
        if (sp!!.getLong("expires_in", 0) - sp.getLong("time_delta", 0) - System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000 <= 60 && !sp.getString("refresh_token", "")!!.isBlank()) updateAccessToken(cont)

        val initialRequest = if (sp.getLong("expires_in", 0) - sp.getLong("time_delta", 0) - System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000 <= 60 && !sp.getString("refresh_token", "")!!.isBlank()) {
            updateAccessToken(cont)
            requestBuilder(chain)
        } else {
            requestBuilder(chain)
        }


        val initialResponse = chain.proceed(initialRequest)

        return if (initialResponse.code == 401 && !sp.getString("refresh_token", "").isNullOrBlank() && sp.getLong("expires_in", 0) - sp.getLong("time_delta", 0) - System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000 <= 60) {
            updateAccessToken(cont)
            initialResponse.close()
            val authorizedRequest = initialRequest
                    .newBuilder()
                    .addHeader("Content-type:", "application/json")
                    .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + cont.getSharedPreferences("app_data", 0).getString("access_token", "")!!)
                    .build()
            chain.proceed(authorizedRequest)
        } else {
            val errorBody = initialResponse.message
            when {

            }
            if (initialResponse.code == 500) {
                val thread = object : Thread() {
                    override fun run() {
                        Looper.prepare()
                        Toast.makeText(cont, cont.getString(R.string.server_error_500), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        Looper.loop()
                    }
                }
                thread.start()
            }
            initialResponse
        }
    }


    private fun updateAccessToken(context: Context) {
        val sp = context.getSharedPreferences("app_data", 0)
        synchronized(this) {
            val tokensCall = accessTokenApi()
                    .getNewToken(ReqAccessToken(context.getSharedPreferences("app_data", 0).getString("refresh_token", "")!!))
                    .execute()

            if (tokensCall.isSuccessful) {
                val responseBody = tokensCall.body()
                val editor = sp.edit()

                val localTime = SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(tokensCall.headers()["Date"]!!)
                Singleton.setServerTime(localTime!!.time / 1000, context)

                editor.putString("access_token", Objects.requireNonNull<ResNewTokens>(responseBody).access_token).apply()
                editor.putString("refresh_token", Objects.requireNonNull<ResNewTokens>(responseBody).refresh_token).apply()
                editor.putLong("expires_in", responseBody!!.expires_in!!).apply()
            } else {
                when (tokensCall.code()) {
                    500 -> {
                        val thread = object : Thread() {
                            override fun run() {
                                Looper.prepare()
                                Toast.makeText(cont, cont.getString(R.string.server_error_500), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                                Looper.loop()
                            }
                        }
                        thread.start()
                    }

                    401 -> {
                        Singleton.logOut(context)
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }


    private fun requestBuilder(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Request {
        return chain.request()
                .newBuilder()
                .header("Content-type:", "application/json")
                .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + cont.getSharedPreferences("app_data", 0).getString("access_token", "")!!)
                .build()
    }

    private fun accessTokenApi(): APIService {
        val interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        interceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY

        val dispatcher = Dispatcher()
        dispatcher.maxRequests = 1


        val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(interceptor)
                .connectTimeout(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .dispatcher(dispatcher)
                .readTimeout(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build()


        client.dispatcher.cancelAll()

        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BuildConfig.API_URL)
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build()

        return retrofit.create(APIService::class.java)
    }
}
```

In general as I see I send request for token refreshing before send request with expired access_token. Maybe someone will have some suggestions or improvements for my solution :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes that is too much simple do not take is difficult, I also have same issue but i solve like this

So When the token is expred so the Retrofit give the

Error Code = 401

So you need to save the data of user Using **sharedPref** the **userEmail** or **userName** as well as **userPassword** So

When the user get token exipre message or error **code 401** then you need to call a method to login the user again to show anything to the user using **useremail** and **userpassword** and then a fresh token generated then send that generated Token to the server and it will work in this case

I hope that will help

Comment: yes, but as I see you receive 401 error and make one more request which return 401 error, and I would like to remove problematic request

Comment: It means that you your token is expired so you need to regenerate your token again and you solve your problem

Comment: you didn't understand me, I would like to prevent getting 401 error requests